# How to add Multiple items in Django Inventory Management System using Django Model Form

Tags: python, django

I tried to develop an Inventory Management System in Django. Here, I got a problem. In order, I can easily add single items. But I want to add multiple items under one invoice number. So, how can I do this? Here is my code below:

models.py:

```py
from django.db import models
from products.models import Category
from customers.models import Customer

# Create your models here.
class Order(models.Model):
    Payment_Choices = (
        ('Cash', "Cash on Delivery"),
        ('Bkash', "Bkash Payment"),
        ('Bank', "Bank"),
    )

    Status_Choices = (
        ('Delivered', "Delivered"),
        ('Pending', "Pending"),
        ('Cancelled', "Cancelled"),
    )
    ref_no = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    customer = models.ForeignKey(Customer, null=True, on_delete=models.SET_NULL)
    category = models.ForeignKey(Category, null=True, on_delete=models.SET_NULL)
    product = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    price = models.IntegerField()
    discount_price = models.IntegerField(blank=True, null=True)
    quantity = models.IntegerField()
    delivery_date = models.DateField()
    payment = models.CharField(max_length=100, choices=Payment_Choices)
    status = models.CharField(max_length=100, choices=Status_Choices)
    date_created = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True, null=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.ref_no

    def get_total_price(self):
        return self.quantity * self.price

    def get_discount_price(self):
        return self.quantity * self.discount_price

    def get_amount_saved(self):
        return self.get_total_price() - self.get_discount_price()

    def get_final_price(self):
        if self.discount_price:
            return self.get_discount_price()
        return self.get_total_price()
```

views.py:

```py
def create_order(request):
    if request.method == "POST":
        forms = OrderForm(request.POST)
        if forms.is_valid():
            forms.save()
            return redirect("order_list")
    else:
        forms = OrderForm()
    context = {
        "forms": forms
    }
    return render(request, "orders/create_order.html", context)
```

forms.py:

```py
from django import forms
from .models import Order

class OrderForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Order
        exclude = ('category', )
        # fields = '__all__'

        widgets = {
            'ref_no': forms.TextInput(attrs={'class': 'form-control'}),
            'product': forms.TextInput(attrs={'class': 'form-control'}),
            'price': forms.NumberInput(attrs={'class': 'form-control'}),
            'discount_price': forms.NumberInput(attrs={'class': 'form-control'}),
            'quantity': forms.NumberInput(attrs={'class': 'form-control'}),
            'delivery_date': forms.DateInput(attrs={'class': 'form-control'}),
            'date_created': forms.DateTimeInput(attrs={'class': 'form-control'}),
        }
```

Customer, Delivery Date, Ref No everything will be once. But product, price, quantity and discount price will be multiple times which I want. How can I do this?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

The first issue I notice is in your `models.py` file, where you've kept `Product` as a `CharField`. Firstly, you cannot do what you want using this approach. You need to use a Relation between the entities `Order` and `Product`. I see that you've created relations with `Customer` and `Category` so why not do the same with `Product`?

Use a `ManyToMany` Relation with `Order` and `Product` with a `field` say `products` inside the `Order` model replacing the `product` field. This will allow you to use `products` inside your form which will also allow you to create an `Order` instance with multiple `Product`s.

If the application is live and you want to avoid data loss, please do not remove the `product` field. First, create the new `products` field, run a script which will transfer the old data to the new field.

**EDIT: Reply to Comment**

I think you need to keep a field `stock` in `Product` model. e.g. Product Cheetos and Lays has 50 items and 100 items in stock. Now, I will order 2 Cheetos and 1 Lays. So, I do two things.

1. I'll change the stock of Cheetos to 48 and Lays to 99
2. Create an Order with two Products Cheetos and Lays, Cheetos with quantity 2 and Lays with quantity 1.

Hope this helps!

Comment: Thanks a lot for your suggestions. Yeah, i did this before. But after doing that, there is another problem arise. That is, Product Quantity. If i use ManyToMany relation i can add multiple products. But, every individual products can have individual quantity. So, how can i do this?

Answer (score 0):

You should have two models:

1. Order Model
2. Orderitem Model FK to order model.

Same goes to the cart.

And orderitems displayed as inlines in admin.